# Azure Web Job won't find Connection String

Tags: c#, azure, f#, web

I have a fairly straightforward Azure Web Job connected to a queue.  I have validated that it works locally.  When I deploy to Azure, however it fails on the issue: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to validate Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK Dashboard connection string

In my job, I set the connection string via hardcode (because I can't get the bloody configuration thing to work anyways)

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let _dashboardConn = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=STUFF;AccountKey=STUFF"        
    let _storageConn = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=STUFF;AccountKey=STUFF"
    let config = new JobHostConfiguration()
    config.DashboardConnectionString <- _dashboardConn
    config.StorageConnectionString <- _storageConn
    let host = new JobHost(config) 
    host.RunAndBlock()
    0
```

So that didn't work, and I decided to set the value in the configuration section of the websites...which also did not work.  It is as though the App.Config does not exist.  Oh, and I made sure that it is set to always copy (just to be sure, I deleted the whole output folder and made it rebuild and ensured it was there and correct).

Comment: I haven't seen that particular error message, but then I've also never used the WebJobs SDK. If you decide to drop the SDK and just write a 'normal' command-line executable, here's an article about configuring it in Azure: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/16/configuring-azure-web-jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following 2 appsettings in Azure Websites "AzureWebJobsDashboard" and "AzureWebJobsStorage". When you run the app in AzureWebsites, our recommendation is to the storage ConnectionString in the AppSetting section.